# Windows vista,MMC could not create the snap-in for event viewer

Tags: windows-vista, itunes, administrator, event-log

I have an issue where a windows vista computer isn't running certain applications (iTunes, Quickbooks, Word). Internet Explorer works fine. Seemingly every program that needs authentication to run is throwing an error. I can't even run event viewer because of the error message above.

In adobe acrobat it says

```
[Window Title]
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe

[Content]
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail.
[OK]
```

In Microsoft Word it says

```
[Window Title]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE

[Content]
This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Create an association in the Set Associations control panel.

[OK]
```

AVG says

```
[Window Title]
C:\Program Files\AVG\AVG9\avgui.exe

[Content]
C:\Program Files\AVG\AVG9\avgui.exe

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail.


[OK]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, the following is output by IE when I type javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent) the following is output...
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6.3; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729) - What is the .NET CLR 1.1.4 doing there, and does it conflict in any way?

Comment: Hmm. done some "cleaning" in the winsxs folder by any chance?

I tried that once.. yeah, it ruins everything, reinstalling apps doesn't help, you pretty much have to rebuild chief.